# Rails many to many relationship validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, many-to-many

I have two models in my rails application: Place and Activity. There is a many to many relation between these two models. The important thing is that a place has to have at least one activity associated, so I'm trying to make a validation on this relation. I've made this:

```
validates :activities, :length => {:minimum => 1} #TODO: there is a better way to do this
```

What I don't like is the error message that I get when trying to insert a place with no activities associated:

```
Activities is too short (minimum is 1 characters)
```

I'd like to get a better message in this case. I'm also not sure this is the best way how to validate a relation like this. I think it could be a good idea to write a custom validation. Or is there a way how achieve this without writing  a custom validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
validates :activities, presence: true
```